# Crystal Reports - obtaining % of random data to display in report

Tags: random, crystal-reports, report, percentage

I will be generating a list of data on a daily basis and the count of data will vary. I would like to see how I can display 15% of the current count of data randomly.

To be more specific, I have a list of contacts that do not respond to the survey. I would like to follow up with 15% of the contacts daily. I would like the report to display only 15% of the contacts at random.

How would I go about completing this in Crystal Reports?

Comment: This should be done on the database side. What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
// (@ Rnd}
// generate a random number between 0 and 14 (inclusive):
Floor(Rnd * 15)
```

Suppress `details` section when `(@Rnd} <> 0`

** edit **

Use this as the `details` section condition-suppression formula:

```
// generate a random number between 0 and 99 (inclusive); suppress all values > 14 (85%)
Floor(Rnd * 100) > 14
```

Comment: +1 For client-side solution. Though, keeping 1 out of 15 records is ~6%, not 15%.

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach:

1. Create a formula `@reset` and place in `report header`.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=0
   ```
2. Place your `contacts` in details section.
3. Create a formula `@count` and place it to the rightmost part of the report.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=count+1;
   count;
   ```
4. Now go to the `section expert` of the `Detail section` and write below formula for supress condition.

   ```
   EvaluateAfter(@Count);
   Shared Numbervar count;
   if (count mod 7)=0
   then true
   else false
   ```

This will make sure that for every 7 records there will be one record displayed and remaining will be supressed, this will be approximately `15 records displayed for every 100 records`

Comment: You really don't need all these formulas, variables, etc. You can replicate this logic much more simply with just the Details Section suppression formula `recordnumber mod 7 <> 0`. That being said, this is _NOT_ randomized and will display the same records every time the report is run (assuming the database and query sort order has not changed).